# memcached like software with disk persistence

Tags: nosql, memcached, couchdb, redis, ehcache

I have an application that runs on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 which needs to store and retrieve a large number of large serialized objects. Currently the store is implemented by simply saving the serialized streams as files, where the filenames equal the md5 hash of the serialized object. However I would like to speed things up replacing the file-store by one that does in-memory caching of objects that are recently read/written, and preferably does the hashing for me.

The design of my application should not get any more complicated. Hence preferably would be a storing back-end that manages a key-value database and caching in an abstracted and efficient way. I am a bit lost with all of the key/value stores that are out there, and much of the topics/information seems to be outdated. I was initially looking at something like memcached+membase, but maybe there are better solutions out there. I looked into redis, mongodb, couchdb, but it is not quite clear to me if they fit my needs.

My most important requirements:

- Transparent saving to a persistent store in a way that the most recently written/read objects are quickly available by automatically caching them in memory.
- Store should survive a reboot. Hence in memory objects should be saved on disk asap.
- Currently I am calculating the md5 manually. It would actually be nicer if the back-end does this for me. Hence the ability to get the hash-key when an object is stored, and be able to retrieve the object later using the hashkey.
- Big plus is that if there are packages available for Ubuntu 12.04, either in universe or through launchpad or whatever.
- Other than this, the software should preferably be light not be more complicated than necessary (I don't need distributed map-reduce jobs, etc)

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Would the app be storing these local to the machine it runs or, or are you planning for it to talk to a server to store these objects? All of the technologies you list are server bits. To run the app and store locally would require installing and running the server locally in addition to the app.

Comment: The OS does in-memory caching on files, so this system is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at `MongoDB`.  It caches things efficiently using your OS to page data in and out, and is pretty simple to setup.  Redis and Memcached won't be good solutions for you because they keep everything in RAM.  Other, simpler solutions like LevelDB or BDB would also probably be suitable.  I don't think any database going to compute hashes automatically for you.  It sounds like you already have code for this though.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally suggest Redis because it will be fast and in-memory with asynch persistant store.  Plus you'll find you can use their different data types for other purposes so not as single-purpose as memcached.  As far as auto-hashing, I don't think it does that as you define your own keys when you store objects (as in most of them).

One downside to Redis is if you're storing a TON of binary objects, you'll be limited to available memory in RAM (unless sharding) so could reach performance limitations.  In that case you may store objects on file system, hash them, and store keys in Redis and match that to filename stored on file server and you'd be fine.

--

An alternate option would be to check out ElasticSearch which is like Mongo in that it stores objects native as JSON, but it includes the Lucene search engine on top with RESTful API interface.  It "warms up" data in memory for fast response, but is also a persistent store and the nicest part is it auto-shards and auto-clusters using multicast to find other nodes.

--

Hope that helps and if so, share the love!  ;-)

Comment: For ElasticSearch, by the way, you'll need to add Java to your stack.  There are rpms you can build for ES as referenced on their site.

Comment: Objects are quite large, and the collection of them will quickly outgrow RAM. Also store should survive a reboot. Does Redis nicely offload everything to disk, or is just in-memory storage?

Comment: Redis persists to disk using snapshotting or redo-logging, but it does not offload the data. They must fit in memory. See http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Comment: For the record the automatic hash key generation is very likely possible with some lua scripting on redis 2.6